# Solution on R group by issue _ multiple combination

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using group by funciton in a dataset using R software. But the target of the id would duplicate. Here is the sample dataset:

```
ID  Var1
A    1
A    3
B    2
C    3
C    1
D    2
```

In tradtional groupby function by each id, I can do

```
DT<- data.table(dataset )
DT[,sum(Var1),by = ID]
```

and get the result:

```
ID  V1
A   4
B   2
C   4
D   2
```

However, I've to group ID by A+B and B+C and D
(PS. say that F=A+B ,G=B+C)
 and the target result dataset below:

```
ID  V1
F   6
G   6
D   2
```

IF I use recoding technique on ID, the duplicate B would be covered twice.
IS there any one have the solution?
MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)     
library(tidyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(F=ifelse(ID %in% c("A", "B"), 1, 0),
              G = ifelse(ID %in% c("B", "C"), 1, 0),
              D = ifelse(ID == "D", 1, 0))

df %>% 
  gather(var, val, F:D) %>% 
  filter(val==1) %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  summarise(V1=sum(V1))

#  # A tibble: 3 x 2
#    var      V1
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 D         2
# 2 F         6
# 3 G         6
```

Comment: I've tyied this way but failed because of the memory limit (the dataset is large)

May I ask Is there another way to solve it?  @NelsonGon

Comment: Try reading the data with `data.table` with any of its `f`* functions. They sometimes offer a speed advantage

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've read the data by data.table:fread . Looking for another way for calculation.　Ａnyway,Thanks!  @NelsonGon